# How can I eliminate printing rows to an Excel sheet, and instead add the desired records (Rows) to an array (VBA)?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, dataset

I have code that does the following:

- Creates a dictionary for items in Production (**Production_Dictionary**) and Development (**Development_Dictionary**)
- Loops over a production dataset that has been assigned to an array (**Production_Array**)
- Using a key (**Production Item**), it checks if the development dataset contains the production record
- If not, it prints the record (row) on a sheet for deleted items (**Delete_Sheet**)
- If so, it checks if any of the columns (fields) have changed
- If a field has changed, it will print the record (row) on a sheet for changed items (Change_Sheet) and highlight the changed fields

**Here is the code, which functions as expected, but is slow:**

```
For i = 1 To UBound(Production_Array, 1) '1 indicates upper-bound of rows
    Production_Item = Production_Array(i, ProductionID_1) & Production_Array(i, ProductionID_2) & Production_Array(i, ProductionID_3)
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Find Deleted Records
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Development_Dictionary.exists(Production_Item) Then 'If Production Item not found in Development
        Delete_Row = Delete_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        Set Delete_Record = Delete_Sheet.Range(Delete_Sheet.Cells(Delete_Row, 1), Delete_Sheet.Cells(Delete_Row, Last_Column_Development))
        Delete_Record = Application.Index(Production_Array, i)
        GoTo LineNext
    End If
    
    ItemRow = Development_Dictionary(Production_Item)
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Find Changed Records
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For x = 1 To Last_Column_Production 'Checking all fields for changes - Only for records found in each data set
        If Production_Array(i, x) <> Development_Array(ItemRow, x) Then

            If Not Pasted_Record Then
                Change_Row = Change_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                Set Change_Record = Change_Sheet.Range(Change_Sheet.Cells(Change_Row, 1), Change_Sheet.Cells(Change_Row, Last_Column_Production))
                Change_Record = Application.Index(Production_Array, i) 'Production_Record.Value
                Pasted_Record = True
            End If

            Change_Sheet.Cells(Change_Row, x).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next x

Pasted_Record = False
LineNext:
Next i
```

I have tried everything I can find on stack overflow to avoid constantly referencing an Excel sheet for each changed/deleted record. My hope was to assign all changed/deleted records to a separate array, and then paste the array on the Excel sheet after I have finished with each dataset.

Application.Index methodologies have been great for returning a row, but not for adding that row to another array with unknown size. I could not get around this issue with Redim Preserve statements, though there was some type of transposing methodology (for application.index) that looked promising, but was too confusing to understand.

Comment: FYI using Application.Index on arrays to get a "slice" (row or column) from the array is super-slow, so I would avoid that if possible.

Comment: Tim, thank you so much for your help. I made a couple minor tweaks to your excerpt (to fit the rest of the code you couldn't see), and it works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't compile or test this, but it should give you some idea on how to handle compiling the "change" and "delete" data.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim ubR As Long, ubC As Long, changes, deletes
    
    '...
    ubR = UBound(ProductionArray, 1)
    ubC = UBound(ProductionArray, 2)
    
    'resize output arrays to max possible required size
    ReDim changes(1 To ubR, 1 To ubC)
    changeNum = 0
    ReDim deletes(1 To ubR, 1 To ubC)
    deleteNum = 0
    
    
    For i = 1 To ubR '1 indicates upper-bound of rows
        
        'should realy use a separator here
        Production_Item = Join(Array(Production_Array(i, ProductionID_1), _
                                     Production_Array(i, ProductionID_2), _
                                     Production_Array(i, ProductionID_3)), "~~")
        
        If Not Development_Dictionary.Exists(Production_Item) Then 'If Production Item not found in Development
            CopyRow Production_Array, i, deletes, deleteNum 'add to deletes array
        Else
            ItemRow = Development_Dictionary(Production_Item)
            'Find Changed Records
            For x = 1 To Last_Column_Production 'Checking all fields for changes - Only for records found in each data set
                If Production_Array(i, x) <> Development_Array(ItemRow, x) Then
                    CopyRow Production_Array, i, changes, changeNum
                    Exit For 'stop checking column values
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next i
    
    'put deletes on worksheet
    If deleteNum > 0 Then
        With Delete_Sheet.Cells(Delete_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.rows.count + 1, "A")
            .Resize(deleteNum, UBound(deletes, 2)).Value = deletes
        End With
    End If
    
    'same for changes...
    
End Sub

'Given two 2D 1-based arrays, copy row `srcRow` from `arrSrc` over to `arrDest`
'  Handles incrementing `destRow` on each call; hence explicit `ByRef`
Sub CopyRow(arrSource, srcRow As Long, arrDest, ByRef destRow As Long)
    Dim col As Long
    destRow = destRow + 1 'increment destination row to copy to
    For col = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2)
        arrDest(destRow, col) = arrSource(srcRow, col)
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies! I almost never post, and this is the first time I have gotten an answer to my inquiry. I have marked it as accepted.